# Positive-frequency modes in an ideal cavity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

For a quantum scalar field in Minkowski spacetime, a set of preferred modes is generally introduced as
$$
f_k\propto e^{i \left(kx-\omega_k t\right)}, 
$$
which is said to be positive-frequency since it satisfies: $\partial_t f_k=-i\omega_k f_k $ for $\omega_k>0$.

In Sean Carroll's book, Spacetime and Geometry, this choice is justified by the ability of an arbitrary inertial observer to distinguish positive and negative-frequency solutions. In his arguments, Carroll considers a boost in the velocity $v=dx/dt$, leading to new coordinates $(x',t')$ given by the Lorentz transformation
$$
t=\gamma\left(t'+vx'\right) \quad \text{and} \quad x=\gamma\left(x'+vt'\right),
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor. Under this transformation, one can show that the time derivative in the new time coordinate $t'$ is given by
$$
\partial_{t'}f_k=\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t'}+\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial t'}=\gamma(-i\omega_k )f_k+\gamma v(ik)f_k=-i\omega_k^{\prime}f_k
$$
where $\omega_k^{\prime}=\gamma(\omega_k-vk)$ is the frequency in the boosted frame. Meaning that we have preserved the positive-frequency definition for the mode functions.

I always thought that this kind of argument would hold for any mode decomposition proportional to $e^{-i\omega t}$ in Minkowski spacetime. For example, consider a scalar quantum field $\hat{\phi}(x,t)$ confined in a one-dimensional ideal cavity composed by a pair of mirrors: one at the origin $x=0$ while the second is fixed at the position $x=L$ (both imposing Dirichlet boundary conditions: $\hat{\phi}(0,t)=\hat{\phi}(L,t)=0$). In this configuration, the set of positive-frequency solutions follow the following pattern of standing waves
$$
g_{k_n}\propto \sin(k_nx)e^{-i\omega_n t}\propto f_{k_n}-f_{-k_n}
$$
with $\omega_{k_n}=k_n=\frac{n\pi}{L}$ for $n=(1,2,\dots)$ and $f_{k_n}$ are the free Minkowskin modes defined previously.

But in this case, by similar arguments one might find instead
$$
\partial_{t'}g_{k_n}(x,t)\propto-i\left[\omega_{k_n}^{\prime}f_{k_n}-\omega_{-k_n}^{\prime}f_{-k_n}\right] \neq -i \omega_{n}^{\prime}g_{k_n}
$$

Why is this so? If one can not distinguish between positive and negative solution, what is the justification for this preferred choice?

On the other hand, it seems that the frequencies $\omega_{k_n}$ must depend only on the lengh $L=\gamma L'$ of the cavity in the two frames. Maybe, by considering the first mirror at position $x=x_0$ such that $g_{k_n}(x,t)\propto \sin[k_n(x-x_0)]e^{-i\omega_{k_n} (t-t_0)}$ one can consider: $k_n(x-x_0)\to k_n'(x'-x_0')$ and $\omega_{k_n} (t-t_0)\to \omega_{k_n}' (t'-t_0')$, in such way that $\partial_{t'}g_{k_{n}}(x',t')=-\omega_{k_n}'g_{k_n}(x',t')$.